# How to use the UPDATE in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working a project using a ASP.NET Webforms. And I am currently on the update part of the project. I want to have a data like this:

**Clock**

```
ID | EmpID | Date     | Clock IN | Morning IN | Morning OUT | Clock OUT
1  |   1   | 07/20/16 | 07:00 am | 09:00 am   | 09:15 am    | 11:00 am 
2  |   1   | 07/21/16 | 08:00 am | 10:00 am   | 10:15 am    | 12:00 pm
```

But I get this instead

**Clock**

```
ID | EmpID | Date     | Clock IN | Morning IN | Morning OUT | Clock OUT
1  |   1   | 07/20/16 | 07:00 am | 10:00 am   | 10:15 am    | 12:00 pm 
2  |   1   | 07/21/16 | 08:00 am | 10:00 am   | 10:15 am    | 12:00 pm
```

Here is the code:

Insert

```
protected void cmdCIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection.Open();

    Response.Write("Welcome!");
    string query = "Insert into [dbo].[Clock] (EmpID,Date,ClockIN) Values ((select EmpID from Emp_Record where ID = @user), @date, @cin)";

    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtID.Text);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cin", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

UPDATE

```
protected void cmdAMIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("You have started your first break");
    myConnection.Open();
    string query = "UPDATE Clock SET MorningIN = @AMIN FROM Emp_Record  INNER JOIN Clock  ON Em_Record.EmpID = Clock.LeadID;";
    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMIN", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

How am I going to use the update command so that the other data will not affect the first one?

Comment: Without a WHERE clause on the UPDATE statement you update every record in the table to the same values. You need to add a _WHERE ID = @UserID_

Comment: Be careful here. Using AddWithValue in pass through sql like this can result in incorrect datatypes. Especially with datetime values. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ It would be better to explicitly name the datatype (or even better would be to use a stored procedure).

Comment: When I use where the morning in row is null. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the update code with a Where statement that tells the db which row to update. Otherwise all rows are updated.

EX: `"UPDATE Clock SET MorningIN = @AMIN FROM Emp_Record INNER JOIN Clock ON Em_Record.EmpID = Clock.LeadID WHERE ID = @idtoupdate;";`

Answer (score 0):

You issue is not about ASP.NET, but SQL.

To troubleshoot, use SQL Server Management Studio (or your favorite sql tool) and execute

```
declare @user int
set @user=1 -- value you enter in txtID.Text
declare @date date
set @date=GETDATE()
declare @cin time
set @cin=GETDATE()

Insert into [dbo].[Clock] (EmpID,Date,ClockIN) 
       Values ((select EmpID from Emp_Record where ID = @user), @date, @cin)
```

and then

```
declare @AMIN time
set @AMIN=GETDATE()

UPDATE Clock SET MorningIN = @AMIN FROM Emp_Record  
       INNER JOIN Clock  ON Em_Record.EmpID = Clock.LeadID;
```

The last query looks wrong and most likely would fail. Try to modify it as

```
UPDATE Clock SET MorningIN = @AMIN FROM Emp_Record t1 
       INNER JOIN Clock t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.ID;
```

and try again. If it would work - it will update MorningIN with the same value for all rows. If you need to update only specific user - then you should provide his ID in the WHERE clause, similar to the first query. Not sure what is the logic, but it could be e.g.

```
UPDATE Clock SET MorningIN = @AMIN FROM Emp_Record t1 
       INNER JOIN Clock t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.ID AND t2.ID = @XXX
```